# How check which query taking time in processlist

Tags: mysql

I have been trying to check slow query in process-list but its showing null & time is huge. Is any other way to check slow queries without enable the logs.

```
| ID      | USER | HOST            | DB          | COMMAND | TIME | STATE     | INFO  | TIME_MS | ROWS_SENT | ROWS_EXAMINED | ROWS_READ |
| 1149040 | test | 127.0.0.1:58759 | NULL      | Sleep     |  206 |           | NULL  |  206054 |         0 |             0 |      6447 |
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
select * from information_schema.processlist where command!='sleep' and time>10;
```

This will return queries take more than 10 seconds and is not in sleep mode.

Comment: @BenayaPaul I changed my answer

Comment: show processlist also showing the same thing expect the condition i need query value instead null

Comment: @BenayaPaul the query can be seen in info field

Comment: @BenayaPaul I changed the answer

Comment: Ya that's fine i need to know null value info.

Comment: You can add *info is null* criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Null value indicates no query is being executed.

Comment: @T.S. It is very relevant. The question is *"Is any other way to check slow queries without enable the logs."*. This answer does not attempt to answer that question.

Comment: the question is: *"Is any other way to check slow queries without enable the logs?"*. Does your answer covers for that? - NO

Comment: @T.S. That's what I just said... Your comment after my review comment says "delete your comment". I was under the impression you meant the review comment, but now I'm not sure.

Comment: @Jesse haha. Sorry. I meant that this answer IS the comment, came into my attention during first answer review. And it wasn't directed @ you. But to the user who posted the answer. If I wanted to direct at you, I use @. My mistake is that I took your comment as it came from the originator of this answer. Now I see that I've made a mistake.